# Deletion of a particular record in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

If  a model exist like

```
    class Empprofile(models.Model):
         name= models.CharField(max_length=255)
         group = models.CharField(max_length=255)
         description = models.CharField(max_length=1024)

    class Details(Empprofile):
       address1=models.CharField(max_length=255)
       address2=models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Views,

```
ep =Empprofile.objects.filter(name="Tom")
for e in ep:
  //How to delete all objects from Details table
```

How to delete all objects Details related to it

Update:Want to delete all rows from Details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `Empprofile` and `Details` classes are two separate, different types of object in the database. Based on the code shown, `Details` takes the *structure* of `Empprofile` and builds on it to make a `Details` model (and associated DB table), but they're not linked at a database level.

Which means that if you want to delete all details to with `name=Tom`, you need to do:

`ep = Details.objects.filter(name="Tom").delete()`

But, sounds like you may have to pause for a moment and check that your model layer is actually structured the way you expect it to be